# how to elegantly handle rule with multiple components in bison

Tags: c++, bison, bisonc++

I use to program in ocaml and use ocalmyacc to generate parser. One very useful feather of ocaml is its variant type like this:

```
type exp = Number of int
| Addexp of exp*exp
```

with such a type, I can construct an AST data structure very elegantly in the parser to represent an exp like this:

```
exp :
number {Number($1)}
| exp1 + exp2 {Addexp($1,$3)}
```

So if there exist similar mechanism in C++ and bison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just match against `exp + exp`. Notice that for a given rule all its actions must have the same declared `%type` assigned to `$$`. In your case it would look something like this:

```
exp: number      { $$ = PrimaryExp($1); }
|    exp '+' exp { $$ = AddExp($1, $2); }
```

Comment: But where is PrimaryExp and AddExp?@ltcmelo

Comment: Those are the function which will create an AST node. It's just an example.

Comment: are PrimaryExp and AddExp some union type? or something that can be inferred by bison ?

Comment: may be I can try to define exp as an union with two structure inside, one for number the other for exp + exp.

Comment: but you suggestion means I need to write a function for each component, whose number may be hundres @ltcmelo

Comment: @shengyushen: you can use inheritance to reduce the work but there will be some boilerplate. Also possible is boost::variant. You should rarely need actions for unit productions as long as your types can handle the necessary conversions. The functions proposed in this answer might be constructors.

Comment: @rici  : I have tried boost.variant with small code segment, and find it actually resolve my problem. It can be even elegant when combined with typedef.

Comment: @shengyushen: Cool. I've used it, and I agree that it can be elegant. Something similar will be in C++17, as I understand it.

Comment: @rici : I am currently writing an awk script to convert my ocaml type variant definition file into c++. For each type,  I wrap its each component with a tuple, and store all these tuples of a type into a boost.variant.